# Why does iloc in pandas sometimes get a column vector and sometimes a row vector？

Tags: pandas

When I was learning the linear regression of Wu Enda's machine learning, I found that`

y2 = data2.iloc[:,-1]`and`y2 = data2.iloc[:,cols2-1:cols2]`will get` y2.shape = ( 1, 47)`and`y2.shape=(47, 1)`, why?

All the data I'm using is data2, but it's because `y2 = data2.iloc[:,-1]`, `y2 = data2.iloc[:,cols2-1:cols2]`The difference between these two causes the operations in the gradient descent algorithm to not work correctly.

Comment: can you provide the output of `data2.to_dict()`?

Comment: Also if should be `(47,)` vs `(47, 1)`, you can't have `(1, 47)` without transposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

    A   B   C   D   E
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

Using `data2.iloc[:,-1]` indexes a single column, thus returning a Series:

```
out = data2.iloc[:,-1]

0     4
1     9
2    14
3    19
4    24
Name: E, dtype: int64

out.shape

(5,)
```

In comparison `data2.iloc[:,cols2-1:cols2]`, **slices** a set of one column, thus yielding a DataFrame:

```
cols2 = 5
out = data2.iloc[:,cols2-1:cols2]

    E
0   4
1   9
2  14
3  19
4  24

out.shape

(5, 1)
```

*Note that slicing with `data2.iloc[:, [-1]]` (note the list), would also give a DataFrame.*

You can find the same mechanism in pure python, indexing or slicing a list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

lst[-1]
# 5

lst[-1:]
# [5]
```